# Integration test for Service/Rest methods in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

As I mention in title, I need to create integration test.

This is my first test in my life.

I need that my integration test call a rest method but I'm getting this error:

This is My test:

```
 @SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
classes = CrewApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:TeamController")
public class TeamIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void integrationTeamTest() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/teams")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ).andReturn();

        System.out.println(mvcResult.getResponse());
    }
}
```

And this is my rest method:

```
@RestController
public class TeamController {

    private final TeamService teamService;
    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public TeamController(TeamService teamService, PersonService personService) {
        this.teamService = teamService;
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/teams")
    public List<TeamDto> findAll() {
        return teamService.findAll();
    }
```

Method work, Junit test work only this integration throw error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Spring unit tests and Spring integration test.

When you want to do an Integrations test you have to actually make a call to the API.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
classes = CrewApplication.class)

public class TeamIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void integrationTeamTest() throws Exception {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/teams", String.class);

        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("TEAM REPRESENTATION AS STRING");
    }
}
```

If you need further information, visit [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) .